# eclipse tycho: Why are line endings modified in files within plugins that are resolved by the target platform?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I have an eclipse tycho (1.6.0) maven project and I've made the following observation:

When I build my project locally on Windows, files (plugin.xml, plugin.properties, etc.) from plugins (packed as jars) that are part of my Target platform (packed as an UpdateSite-zip file) have Windows (CRLF) line endings.

When my project is built by a CI-CD pipeline on Linux VMs, the same files from the same plugins (packed as jars) from the same Target platform (packed as an UpdateSite-zip file) have Linux line endings.

It seems, that tycho is extracting the Target platform ZIP-file and the Plugin JAR-files locally and pack everything into my UpdateSite zip file. This seems like a bug because external dependencies shouldn't be modified. or am I missing something?

**Environments:**

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit or an Ubuntu
- Maven: 3.6.3
- Java: Oracle JDK 1.8_2XX
- Target platform is provided by an Artifactory virtual p2 repository as a UpdateSite zip file

Comment: Possibly it is using the setting from Preferences > General > Workspace > "new text file line delimiter"

Comment: @greg-449 the effect is completely IDE independent. In both cases, I build my UpdateSite with Maven in the CMD/Bash. There is no Eclipse IDE involved.